# Please don't edit closeable posts using the edit button from the close votes review queue

Tags: discussion, announcement, editing, close-votes

When you click the **Edit** button in the close votes review queue, it knocks the post out of the queue, so other reviewers will not see it and it will probably not get closed. This is very bad if the post is one that should be closed.

If you want to vote to **Leave Open**, do so - it takes three **Leave Open** votes to remove a post from the queue - the **Edit** button is a hammer and should only be used if you are **absolutely sure** your edit to the question justifies keeping it open.

If you want to edit to make corrections anyway, that's great; just click the link button to the right of the post, then edit (or suggest an edit) as normal. If you want to edit the post and you think the post should be left open but you are not sure enough to hammer it out of the queue (I am often in this situation) then do as above, return to the queue and click **Leave Open**.

If you accidentally **Edit** a post from the queue that you think should be closed, then find the post and cast a close vote to put it back in the queue, or come into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52824/the-greenhouse) so someone else can take a look.

Comment: If you want to read everything (if you're a moderator or an avid user), on a small site like this one you can alternatively park on [the 'active' view](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) of the site, and thus see every new post and every edit, regardless of whether it's in the review queue. Or use [the 'newest' view](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) to review all new questions.

Comment: OK,we will take care!

Comment: @ChrisW I believe it's only possible to see if a post has been edited specifically from review by looking at the queue's general history page, which is only available to those with "access moderator tools" privilege.